# php assign unique variable foreach iteration of array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I Want to assign each set of array in foreach loop to be assigned in unique variable

I have formed an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Mobiles & Accessories
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Mobile Accessories
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Cables
    )

)
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Computers
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => TV & Video Accessories
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Cables
    )

)
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Home Entertainment
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Video Players & Accessories
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Video Accessories
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Cables
    )

)
```

I want each array set to be in unique variables

like

```
$a = (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Mobiles & Accessories
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Mobile Accessories
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Cables
    )

)

$b = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Computers
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => TV & Video Accessories
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Cables
    )

)

$c = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Home Entertainment
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Video Players & Accessories
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Video Accessories
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Cables
    )

)
```

etc., Any help Please

Comment: where's your `foreach` iteration?

Comment: And post your attempts too

Comment: Those are **some** arrays, not _an array!_

Comment: foreach($category_path['subcat'] as $key=>$values){

Comment: Thank you all. Let me try to restate my question - We are fetching multiple hierarchies of category paths in arrays , now the 3 level to 5 level path which consists of for example in a 3 level scenario "Mobiles & Accessories,Mobile Accessories,Cables" needs to be concatenated and placed in a variable and then inserted in a column, now the API response per product has several of these in array of arrays. We are trying to insert unique paths per product in a table. We know there can be a max of 5 paths so we have these as 5 cat_path (1-5) columns/attributes to insert . Amazon site has the paths.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for "[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#language.variables.variable)".

> Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names.
>   That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically.

```
<?php
// your arrays
$arrI = [
    ['title' => 'Mobiles & Accessories'],
    ['title' => 'Mobile Accessories'],
    ['title' => 'Cables']
];
$arrII = [
    ['title' => 'Computers'],
    ['title' => 'TV & Video Accessories'],
    ['title' => 'Cables']
];
$arrIII = [
    ['title' => 'Home Entertainment'],
    ['title' => 'Video Players & Accessories'],
    ['title' => 'Video Accessories'],
    ['title' => 'Cables']
];

// You may access the arrays through the following names
$names = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// The arrays
$arrays = array($arrI, $arrII, $arrIII);

// Now, create variables named after the $names array elements,
// and associate each one with the corresponding array in the $arrays by the defined order.
for($i = 0; $i<count($names); $i++)
    $$names[$i] = $arrays[$i];

// Now, you can access the arrays using their new names!
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($b);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($c);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Initially I have used foreach to iterate the arrays in this way 
foreach($category_path['categoryPath'] as $key=>$values){print_r($values) } 
I am getting the output as I mentioned. Now I need to Iterate these arrays with in the foreach loop to store into the Mysql database in different coloumn

Comment: @DineshGopal I don't get it!! if you can access the arrays to print them out, then, you can access them to also use them elsewhere!!

Comment: Let me try to restate my question - We are fetching multiple hierarchies of category paths in arrays , now the 3 level to 5 level path which consists of for example in a 3 level scenario "Mobiles & Accessories,Mobile Accessories,Cables" needs to be concatenated and placed in a variable and then inserted in a column, now the API response per product has several of these in array of arrays. We are trying to insert unique paths per product in a table. We know there can be a max of 5 paths so we have these as 5 cat_path (1-5) columns/attributes to insert . Amazon site has the paths.

Comment: @DineshGopal that is not a _restating!!_ that's a totally new question, however, to make the things clear, you need to provide what you've tried so far, and spot the issue you have problem on.

Comment: I have tried to state what I have tried so far, I need help concatenating the results of the array (1-5 levels) into a single variable, which I can then insert into a column

Comment: Implode does not seem to concatenate all three levels into one variable

Comment: @DineshGopal Try this and report back! (use the `$arrI` in my answer) : `$out2=array();foreach($arrI as $array)$out2[]=$array['title'];echo implode('/', $out2);`

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in on line 29

Comment: Solved by replacing $$names[$i] with ${$names[$i]}